# Set a Date Value to a Date Field in AX2012

Tags: x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax, morph-x

I'm new in `ax2012` and i create a new `table` with a `field`  of type `date`, then i create new `form` to submit rocords

In `form` a create a new `dateEdite` control and in `EDT property` I specified `TransEdite` to show icon calendare in form.

My problem is when i try submit form, i can't `insert` date value in date field.

how can I fix that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that DataField and DataSource of the forms control are pointing to your date field on the table?

If it is a transaction table you are creating, best make use of EDT "TransDate" as data type.